# Where can I find the last successful build?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sourcegear-vault

We re-branched our release version of code to create a new Development branch. Since I had a project explicitly defined beneath the parent of the branch, it did NOT set the new "working folder". Therefore, my "GetLatestVersion" overwrote all of the code that I was working on.

So, how can I get the last successful build for my project? Where does it exist on my machine? If VS2010 can launch the last successful build, it's got to be saved someplace...

Comment: What source control system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where I found the "last successful build" of my ASP.NET web application, AFTER I tried to build and had build errors, which in turn wiped out the bin\Debug folder. (I never understood why Microsoft had the feature "Do you want to run the last successful build?" option when you encounter a build failure...

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\feeb4296\a2914fb6\assembly\dl3\e116d84d\f9632d40_e7aecc01

Answer (score 2):

The last successfull build will be in your project's output path location, which looks like this by default:

```
path\to\your\project\[ConfigurationName]\bin
```

where ConfigurationName is Debug, Release, or a custom configuration. Check the path in your project properties in the Build tab.

Comment: Unless the project specifies otherwise.

Comment: Apparently I can't answer my own question because my reputation isn't high enough...

Found it, just did a search against my entire C drive for my compiled assembly name.

Comment: @ganders: It's always in the last place you look.

Comment: @ganders I'm not sure if that would qualify as an answers. You would need to say where you found it, and why it ended up there.  Also you can edit your question to put more information in as you find it.  By supplying the source control system you are using (as suggested by dougajmcdonald) this would make it easier for people to tell you where you can find your code, and why it is going there.  This would  make it easier for you to find it in the future.

Comment: Apologize...I'm using SourceGear Vault, and the location that I found the file was at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\feeb4296\a2914fb6\assembly\dl3\e116d84d\f9632d40_e7aecc01, obviously that's a random set of folders beneath the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder....

Hopefully that helps people. Let me know if I'm still leaving more stuff out and I'll add to it.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you open the properties of your application project and select the Build tab you can see the output path. If the path is relative (the default) like it is in the screen shot then you'll find the folder in the location your project files are stored.

[image]

Comment: This was empty, which is why I was freaking out. This is a website, so not sure if it works different, but as soon as it started to compile (the version w/o my code), it deleted the entire contents of the bin folder.

Comment: That's kind of how it works - clearing out the build location before compilation. When you say "web project" do you mean ASP .NET WebForms?